# PCL Libraries in Xamarin on OSX Yosemite 10.10

Tags: c#, ios, macos, xamarin, portable-class-library

last week i tried to start work on an iOS Port of my clients software which does consists of many Portable Class Libraries (that also target Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android platforms)

As our Mac Build Machines work with OS X 10.10 Yosemite, i am unable to work with my Visual Studio Development Machine (since the Build Host does not work anymore with OS X 10.10), so i decided to work directly on the Mac with Xamarin Studio. But now i always get an error:

**.../Portable.csproj(1,1): *Error: Unknown MSBuild failure.* Please try building the project again (Portable)**

when i include an Portable Project in my solution. "Normal" class libraries work very well. Do i need some additional packages to work with portable class libraries on an Mac?

Steps to Reproduce:

- New Solution (in Xamarin Studio for Mac)
- Add new Project (Portable Class Library)
- Build

WTH?

Comment: Why negative vote? If i did something wrong, tell me what!

Comment: This does also happen with the current BETA version of Xamarin Studio

Comment: Same problem here on Yosemite

Comment: Stable version of XS fails the build, but for another reason.FYI

Answer (score 2):

Change your solution location, it worked to me.

Comment: I had the same problem and moved the code to a shorter path and it started working. Maybe something similar to the 255 character path limit that Visual Studio has?

Comment: The issue I had seems to be related to odd characters in the path (in my case a %20 that got inserted).

Answer (score 0):

IMHO your installation is broken. I don't have any problems with Xamarin Studio and Yosemite. Please uninstall everythhing Xamarin and Mono related and reinstall it.

Comment: i already did a complete reinstallation of the whole machine. but i'll try a second time. :(

Comment: Reinstallation ended up in the same result. Now, i'll try moving back to Mavericks